# GPS disabling feature

Tags: android

I am developing a app.. When i start the app my GPS is enabled but on exit it should disable the GPS. how to do it? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its not possible.

Try something like this:

```
LocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListener);
```

I hope it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable GPS by the given code.It is working well.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not disable anything ,  just remove gpsupdate using Location Manager..
Here  the code for that

(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE).removeUpdates(mLocListener);